# How do I get my highest match from my findings

Tags: python

Hi im new to coding and i know this may be a a stupid question but i want to get my highest match from my output but dont know how i would do this. I shall put my example below:

```
I want to be able to get the highest match and help would be appreciated
```

Comment: what does *highest* match mean in this context? and  `str_seq` is not defined. you should probably describe what you are trying to do in words...

Comment: What output you want?

Comment: It means the highest % of the primer matching to Seq1

Comment: I have many results i want to be able to filter it to the highest match

Comment: sorry about the str_seq just edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a short version:

```
def frac(part, primer=primer):
    return sum(pa == pr for pa, pr in zip(part, primer)) / len(primer)


mx_i = max(range(len(Seq1) - len(primer)),
           key=lambda i: frac(Seq1[i:i + len(primer)]))

mx_seq = Seq1[mx_i:mx_i+len(primer)]
mx_ratio = frac(mx_seq)

print(f"sequence {mx_seq} starting at index {mx_i} has a {mx_ratio:7.2%} match")
```

`frac` calculates the fraction where the characters match using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). it uses that `True` is basically `1` (and `False` is `0`) in python and can therefore be [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)med.

then it uses [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) in order to get the maximal start-index; the maximum is calculated by calling `frac`.

from the index `mx_i` it then finds the corresponding sequence `mx_seq = Seq1[mx_i:mx_i+len(primer)]` and re-calculated the fraction in order to print it out.

Comment: Hi this solved my problem i was wondering what does the 6.2% mean in the print

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec . should have been: `:7.2`. the `%` means i want the value in percent: the `7` that it should take up at least `7` characters (including the `%` and the `.`) and the `2`  that i want 2 decimal places (behind the dot).

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional if statement to your code:

```
frag_count = 0
highest_match = 0
for comps in part_list_1:
    frag_count = frag_count + 1
    count = 0
    for x in range(0, len(comps), 1):
        if comps[x]== primer[x]:
            count = count +1
    if not count == 0:
        match = (count/len(comps))*100
    else: 
        match = 0
    print("{0} (fragment{1}) has a {2}% match".format(comps, frag_count, match))
    if match > highest_match:
        highest_match = match
```